Surjective map of Kähler manifolds induces injection on cohomology
I'm struggling to understand this detail in a proof by Voisin, in her Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry I. The statement is this: if $\varphi: X \to Y$ is a surjective holomorphic map of two (compact) complex manifolds, with $X$ Kähler, then the map $\varphi^\ast: H^k(Y, \mathbb{Q}) \to H^k(X, \mathbb{Q})$ is injective for all $k$.
Suppose $Y$ is connected and set $r = \dim{X} - \dim{Y}$. If $\omega$ is a Kähler form on $X$ and $\eta \in H^{2n}(Y, \mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}$ is a nonzero element (where $n  = \dim{Y}$), which we assume to be positive w.r.t. the natural orientation, Voisin claims that the form $\varphi^\ast \eta \wedge \omega^r$ is positive on the points where the differential $d\varphi_\ast$ is surjective and $0$ at the points where it is not. I understand the second point, but why must $\varphi^\ast \eta \wedge \omega^r$ be positive on the points where $\varphi$ is submersive?

This is just a linear algebra fact.

The statement you quoted is false unless $X$ is compact. For example, consider the projection $\mathbb C^n\to T$, where $T = \mathbb C^n/\Lambda$ is a complex torus.

You're correct, $X$ is compact (so in particular Poincaré duality holds). Sorry about that.

@MoisheKohan Would you be willing to elaborate?

Try picking points $x \in X$ and $y = f(x) \in Y$ and charts centered on each point, and arrange the charts so that $\omega$ is the standard Kahler form at $x$ and $\eta$ is the standard volume form at $y$. Does that help with the calculations?

Yes, that helps; I realize now that you only care about the order $0$ information, so a large swath of reductions can be made.
